# why does this code takes more time for 190 words message?

Tags: python

```py
class LanguageEvaluator:
    def __init__(self, english_words_file='words.txt', min_word_len=4, min_non_english_count=4):
        self.min_word_len = min_word_len
        self.file_path = english_words_file
        self.min_non_english_count = min_non_english_count
        self.english_words = set()

    async def load_english_words(self):
        if not self.english_words:
            with open(self.file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                self.english_words = {word.strip().lower() for word in file}
        return self.english_words

    async def preprocess_text(self, text):
        words = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text.lower())
        return [word for word in words if len(word) >= self.min_word_len and not word.startswith('@') and not re.match(r'^https?://', word)]

    async def count_non_english_words(self, words):
        english_words = await self.load_english_words()
        return sum(1 for word in words if not any(english_word.startswith(word) for english_word in english_words))

    async def is_english_custom(self, text):
        words_in_text = await self.preprocess_text(text)
        non_english_count = await self.count_non_english_words(words_in_text)
        print(f"Non-English words count: {non_english_count}")
        return non_english_count <= self.min_non_english_count

    async def count_duplicate_words(self, text):
        words = await self.preprocess_text(text)
        word_counts = Counter(words)
        duplicate_count = sum(
            count - 1 for count in word_counts.values() if count > 1)
        return duplicate_count
```

i am using this code to evaluate whether the given sentence is english or not the words.txt has 467k lines of words the issue is when i pass big message like with 190 words it takes like 20sec to check it.... is there any faster way to do so?

i am expecting it to be like 1-2 seconds on checing but it takes like 20+ seconds for big messages

Comment: Doing `for english_word in english_words` for every word of your input makes this algorithm `O(english words * input words)` complexity. Also, do you know what the `async` keyword *does*? Because you have a bunch of `async` functions that only `await` each other rather than anything actually useful, so that's just wasting time creating unnecessary coroutines.

Comment: The regular expression can never return words that start with `@` or `https://`. So there's no need to check for that in the list comprehension. You could also put the minimum word length in the regexp.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `any()` to test if an input word begins with any of the English words, you could try converting the word list to a regular expression. The regexp engine may be able to optimize this to a more efficient test (something equivalent to a B-tree search).

```
    async def load_english_words(self):
        if not self.english_words:
            with open(self.file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                self.english_words = {word.strip().lower() for word in file}
        self.english_prefix_regexp = re.compile('^(' + '|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in self.english_words) + ')')
        return self.english_words

    def is_english_word(self, word):
        return self.english_prefix_regexp.search(word) is not None

    async def count_non_english_words(self, words):
        await self.load_english_words()
        return sum(not self.is_english_word(word) for word in words)
```